# As a non-Burmese citizen, do I have to pay the Bagan Entry Fee when I exit Nyaung-U Airport (NYU), or does that depend on where I am heading to?

Tags: fees-and-charges, myanmar, bagan, nyu

As a non-Burmese citizen, do I have to blindly pay the Bagan Entry Fee (25k kyats in November 2019, a.k.a. tourist fee or Bagan Archaeological Zone fee) when I exit [Nyaung-U Airport (NYU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyaung_U_Airport) (near [Bagan, Myanmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagan)), or does that depend on where I am heading to?

Comment: It sounds like you should, but also that it is possible to avoid it. What penalties are levied if found to have evaded paying I have no idea.

Comment: @simonatrcl thanks, where did you read that one must pay the fee regardless of where one is headed to?

Comment: Simple googling 'Bagan Entry Fee'. This also shows me that you only have to pay it if you actually entry the zone. If you're just changing planes, or going somewhere else in whatever way from Nyuang-U and not entering the zone then you don't. (I'm not putting this as an answer as it's all found from a simple web search, and then non-governmental i.e. not authoritative web sites.)

Comment: @simonatrcl Thanks, yes some of those pages were of doubtful quality and/or assume that the visitor will visit the historical sites. That's why I'm asking here :-)

Comment: Are you asking out of need (as it were) or to get a categorical answer on the site? If the latter I apologise and delete my comments!

Comment: @simonatrcl No worries, please let's keep the comments for now because otherwise I think someone else will write the same :-) I'm asking to make sure I follow the Burmese regulations while not unnecessarily overpaying.

Comment: OK according to https://blog.prepscholar.com/bagan-myanmar-temples you have to pay at the airport (but it doesn't say anything about going elsewhere). Info about avoiding it is from https://nomadjoseph.com/how-to-avoid-bagan-entry-fee/ but it appears to me to assume a different means of arrival. Some other links seem to imply that the fee is $30 (30k kyats) not $25 but that may have been the result of a scam. Have a great trip!