# Who checks whether one has paid the Bagan Entry Fee, and in which location(s) such checks are performed?

Tags: fees-and-charges, myanmar, bagan

Non-Burmese citizens visiting [Bagan, Myanmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagan) [have to pay the Bagan Entry Fee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/149991/1810) (25k kyats in November 2019, a.k.a. tourist fee or Bagan Archaeological Zone fee). The fee may be paid, for example, at the [Nyaung-U Airport (NYU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyaung_U_Airport).

Who checks whether one has paid the Bagan Entry Fee, and in which location(s) such checks are performed?

Motivation for asking this question: I am reading that there are some individuals attempting to scam tourists based on the Bagan Entry Fee, and as a result I would like to clearly understand how the fee works.